# How can I get precision and scale of Teradata's number type through JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, teradata

In Teradata, we can define Number type by something like `Number(*) or Number`, per [guideline](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Data-Types-and-Literals/June-2017/Numeric-Data-Types/NUMBER-Data-Type) from Teradata, the definition

> indicate NUMBER with the system limits for precision and scale

The precision and scale is not fixed defined and depends on so-called *system limit*.

I used `resultSet.getMetaData.getPrecision(index)` and `resultSet.getMetaData.getPrecision(index)`to get the `precision` and `scale` and found that the `precision` equals to `40` and the `scale` equals to `0` in that case.

The precision and scale returned from JDBC is obviously not consistent with Teradata, although we don't know the specific scale limit here, it's indeed a value larger than `0`, or it would contrary to the so-called *system limit*.

We can do a practice by creating a table in Teradata with something like:

`create set table test_db.test(id BIGINT, column1 NUMBER, column2 NUMBER) PRIMARY INDEX (id);`

And insert data with large scale like 12.3456789, the above insert is valid and shows that the JDBC returned scale is actually not correct? How can I get the correct scale value through JDBC?

Note, if the `Number` is defined with explicit precision and scale, like:
`create set table test_db.test_with_explicit_ps(id BIGINT, column1 NUMBER(20,10), column2 NUMBER(28,10)) PRIMARY INDEX (id);`
JDBC can return correct precision and scale by `resultSet.getMetaData.getPrecision/Scale(index)`.

Comment: It rather sounds like you cannot get this information through the JDBC driver. You should file a bug or improvement request with Teradata to address this in their driver.

Comment: However, a quick look at the docs, suggests to me that the scale of a `NUMBER` is flexible (i.e. it isn't fixed for all values in the column, but is per-value), which means it wouldn't be possible to provide a general answer, and in that case `0` is probably the "best" response.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, thanks for your response. Agreed that the Number(*) more like a flexible way to define scale and precision. But it has some limitations in some scenarios like what I met, I need to know the exact scale info and pass the meta info to downstream part. The downstream will round fractional data into integer if scale equals 0.

Comment: Then I'm thinking about once `scale == 0` is detected, just pass sth like `scale == 10` to downstream, but it does not that make sense since the scale itself from Teradata can be 0 if the Number is defined like `Number(20,0)`.

Comment: As @MarkRotteveel wrote there's no known/fixed scale and precision for NUMBER(*), as it can be different for each value, stroring 0.0000012345 in row #1 and 123456789.01 in row #2, you can even store scientific notation like 1.23e-80 in row #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC API Specification for the ResultSetMetaData.getScale method says "Gets the designated column's number of digits to right of the decimal point. 0 is returned for data types where the scale is not applicable."

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getScale(int)

When the scale is omitted for the NUMBER data type, or the asterisk (*) is specified for the scale of the NUMBER data type, then the Teradata Database indicates to the Teradata JDBC Driver that the scale is not available.

In that situation, when the database tells the JDBC Driver that the scale is not available, then the JDBC Driver returns zero (0) for the scale from the ResultSetMetaData.getScale method, per the JDBC API Specification.